# How to acces key from obj in react Oncse in a List & How to remove key error in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I am facing two errors:
I have JSON data that I am fetching from APIs.

```
[
    {
        "title": "Basic Structures & Algoritums",
        "lesson_id": 3,
        "topics": {
            "Title": "Django Project Setup",
            "id": 5
        }
    },
    {
        "title": "Templates Views in Django",
        "lesson_id": 6,
        "topics": {
            "Title": "Template & views",
            "id": 4
        }
    }
]
```

I am accessing it in my list
1 **First Problem is that it loops two times**
Here My Loop Code and result

```
<List>

                    {LessonList.map((lesson) =>
                        <>
                            <ListItem button className={classes.LessonTitle} key={lesson.title}>
                                <ListItemIcon>
                                    <FiberManualRecordOutlinedIcon />
                                </ListItemIcon>
                                <NavLink exact activeClassName="active_class" className={classes.textColor} to={"/lessons/" + lesson.lesson_id}>
                                    <ListItemText primary={lesson.title} />
                                </NavLink>
                            </ListItem>

                            {Object.entries(lesson.topics).map((t, i) => (
                                <ListItem button className={classes.LessonTopics} key={i}>
                                    <ListItemIcon>
                                        <FiberManualRecordIcon />
                                    </ListItemIcon>
                                    <NavLink exact activeClassName="active_class" className={classes.textColor} to={"/play/" + lesson.topics['id']}>
                                        <ListItemText primary={lesson.topics['Title']} />
                                    </NavLink>
                                </ListItem>
                            ))}
                        </>
                    )}

                </List>
```

The result will be shown But it printing the **Title Two Times**
[image]

2 **Problem is That it shows me ket error in the Drawer of material UI component in which this list is rendered**

[image]

I know These are minor issues but I can find a way on the internet.

Comment: why are you mapping over object entries? I think that's why you are having title 2 times because in map you are passing same title with `lesson.topics['Title']`

Comment: I don't think there is any other way to loop over obj. if so then pls tell me?

Comment: Is there any specific requirement to loop over object? you can directly access data from object with `lesson.topics.Title`

Comment: yes because I need a topic id so I can navigate it. Like I do in The top loop '<NavLink exact activeClassName="active_class" className={classes.textColor} to={"/lessons/" + lesson.lesson_id}>
                                    <ListItemText primary={lesson.title} />
                                </NavLink>'

Comment: you can access topic id with `lesson.topics.id`. So no need to loop through object.

Comment: can u send me an sample data?

Comment: Problem is that I have many topics in Lesson

Comment: Then your `topics` will be array, am I right?

Comment: yes I solved it bro with your help No I my data look like this  :{
        "title": "Basic Structures & Algoritums",
        "lesson_id": 3,
        "topics": {
            "5": "Django Project Setup",
            "6": "Books for Study"
        }
    },

Comment: But i am unable to loop can u explain how can I loop now

Comment: I have added answer of your question. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As discussed in comments I think you are looking for below:-

```
{LessonList.map((lesson) =>
                        <>
                            <ListItem button className={classes.LessonTitle} key={lesson.title}>
                                <ListItemIcon>
                                    <FiberManualRecordOutlinedIcon />
                                </ListItemIcon>
                                <NavLink exact activeClassName="active_class" className={classes.textColor} to={"/lessons/" + lesson.lesson_id}>
                                    <ListItemText primary={lesson.title} />
                                </NavLink>
                            </ListItem>

                            {Object.entries(lesson.topics).map((value, index) => (
                                <ListItem button className={classes.LessonTopics} key={value[0]}>
                                    <ListItemIcon>
                                        <FiberManualRecordIcon />
                                    </ListItemIcon>
                                    <NavLink exact activeClassName="active_class" className={classes.textColor} to={"/play/" + value[0]}>
                                        <ListItemText primary={value[1]} />
                                    </NavLink>
                                </ListItem>
                            ))}
                        </>
                    )}
```